# Python: 4/5=0.0. Float declaration missing?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Apologies if this has already been asked but why does this:

```
a=4
b=5
c=float(a/b)

print c
```

Gives

```
>>>>
0.0
```

rather than 0.8?

Comment: in python 3 you get 0.8. It's different depending on python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, division between 2 integers will return an integer (rounding to the closest integer to 0), in this case, `0`.  Your code is basically `float(0)` which is `0.0`.

You would need to change one of your values to a float first if you want to return a float.

This behavior is changed in Python 3, where division between 2 integers will return a float, `0.8` in this case.

Answer (score 4):

That's because this is an integer division:

```
>>> 4/5
0
```

if you want to get `0.8`, cast one of the two to float before the division:

```
>>> 4/float(5)
0.8
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to introduce float in one of the variables. You could do this:

```
from __future__ import division

4/5
```

This will give what you are looking for 0.8, without having to introduce floating.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2 `/` returns only integer part if you use two integers - like `int(0.8)`. You have to use float ie. `float(a)` or `4.0` (shortly `4.`) or `* 1.0`

```
print float(4)/5
print 4/float(5)

print 4.0/5
print 4/5.0

print 4./5
print 4/5.

print a*1.0/b   # sometimes you can see this method 
print a/(b*1.0) # this version need () - without () you get (a/b)*1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`4/5` will return 0 because it's an int division, then you cast float on 0

Answer (score 0):

Because of integer division....dividing two integers will return and integer. The value of 0.8 is truncated to 0.

You need to elevate one of your integers to a float if you want a floating point answer.

E.G.

c = float(a) / b

Comment: It is not truncated. `4/5` already yields `0`.